# Are there any tools in Google Search Console for removing URLs with 301 redirects?

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, url, 301-redirect

In Google Search Console, I am getting 15-20 all different URLs in 404 section which is not in proper format(this URL is too old around 6-7 years and there is no 'Linked from' for this URLs). I want them to redirect to current URL(proper URL which is currently live).

Now one way is to use **.htaccess**, but the problem with this approach once this URLs crawl by google, a rule is no use(it will just occupy space and will execute(just as check whether rule matches or not) for a genuine request which we want to avoid).

Another approach is to redirect it from **server side code**.(which also we don't want as we have to write logic for all these different URLs).

So I just want to is there any available tool for redirecting this type of URL direct using Google Search Console (i.e., is there *any* URL removal tool)?

```
  Url in webmaster           |     Redirect URL(new url)
 ----------------------------|-------------------------
 1) www.xxx.xxx/bmw-c/       |   www.xxx.xxx/bmw-cars/
 2) www.xxx.xxx/bmw-car/     |   www.xxx.xxx/bmw-car/
 3) www.xxx.xxx/hyundai/     |   www.xxx.xxx/hyundai-cars/
 4) www.xxx.xxx/audi-a8/     |   www.xxx.xxx/audi-a8-cars/
 5) www.xxx.xxx/bmw-car-in/  |   www.xxx.xxx/bmw-cars/
```

please note that this just example to show how URL we are getting in webmaster. for this type of URL we just want something that we add new URL and google start redirecting this old URL to new URL. **(not .htaccess)**

So is there any tool for 301-redirect in webmaster(like URL removal tool)?

Comment: You already have an answer that says that such a tool does not exist. 
 Google will never create such a tool either.  It would enable the problematic condition of telling Google that something redirects one way but have users see something different at that URL.   Google likes to crawl your site and see results there.   Very few Google tools allow you to override how your site looks and acts.

Comment: *...a rule is no use(it will just occupy space and will execute(just as check whether rule matches or not) for a genuine request which we want to avoid)...* These do not seem like valid objections to me. This is not a problem and should never be.

Comment: "... redirect it from **server side code**" - FWIW, this would be the preferred method in this situation; not `.htaccess`. Specifically, only execute the redirect logic when you have already deemed that the request would otherwise result in a 404.

Answer (score 5):

No, there doesn't have anything like that and it's logical and make sense. You can't optimise your website just for Google. You must optimise your website for your users, not search engines.

> However, some redirects deceive search engines or display content to
>   human users that is different than that made available to crawlers.
>   It's a violation of Google Webmaster Guidelines to redirect a user to
>   a different page with the intent to display content other than what
>   was made available to the search engine crawler.

This is from Google Quality guidelines about [Sneaky Redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721217) This is the reason why it's not possible and won't be possible as you can give to users 404, but for Google redirect. (At least without violating Google Webmaster Guidelines)

You must do redirects on your server in one or another way.